# XML SOAP save to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, codeigniter, xml-parsing

I have an XML file

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
   <s:Body>
     <GetAllItemCategoryResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
       <GetAllItemCategoryResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HQService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <a:ItemsCategory>
         <a:Code>prov</a:Code>
         <a:Description>Te Fresketa</a:Description>
         <a:LastModifiedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</a:LastModifiedDate>
         <a:active>true</a:active>
         </a:ItemsCategory>       
       </GetAllItemCategoryResult>
     </GetAllItemCategoryResponse>
   </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

I need to read this file and store the records to the database.
Till now i have managed to upload and read the records however i cannot store them in my database. I have looked at this example which has similar XML format with my case but it does not work [PHP - converting XML to array in PHP - parsing a soap xml in php and storing it in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514304/php-converting-xml-to-array-in-php-parsing-a-soap-xml-in-php-and-storing-it)

I am using CodeIgniter(below is my code)

```
function set_xml()
{
    if ($this->input->post('submit'))
    {

        //uploading the file to the server
        if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){
            $this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        }

    }

    $xml = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/').'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    $fh = fopen($xml,'r');
    $theData = fread($fh,filesize($xml));
    fclose($fh);

            $element = new simpleXMLElement($theData);
    $centerElement = $element->Body->GetAllItemCategoryResponse->GetAllItemCategoryResult->ItemsCategory;

    $center = array(
        $centerElement->Code
    );

    var_dump($centerElement);

}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question regarding saving to the database, or accessing the elements in the XML?

I suspect the latter is the case, and the namespaces are throwing you off.

See the following example which accesses the elements from your SOAP response:

```
$xml = file_get_contents(realpath(APPPATH . '../public/').'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name']); 
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml,NULL,false, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$doc->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HQService');


foreach ($doc->xpath('//a:ItemsCategory') as $category) {
    foreach ($category->children('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HQService') as $child) {
        echo $child->getName() . ":" . (string)$child . "\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Code:prov
Description:Te Fresketa
LastModifiedDate:0001-01-01T00:00:00
active:true
```

After that, just save to the database as you like.  Hope this helps!