# How to serialize soap xml to object PHP using soapclient

Tags: php, soap-client

Currently, I am able to send a soap request to a endpoint and get response results serialized std class object using SoapClient. (PHP5)

I've a question here, what if i have a physical xml file (a soap response file) and i want to serialize it back to std class object. Is there any examples or method to do this?

Comment: Question maybe a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514304/php-converting-xml-to-array-in-php-parsing-a-soap-xml-in-php-and-storing-it