# soap response in array

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I am trying to get a soap response in php. It keeps coming as an object onto my web browser but not as xml. WSDL shows as XML but not the response received. Below is my server side code. The soap server is Zend Soap

```
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
    if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])){
        $wsdl = 'http://localhost/webservice/soap';

        $autoDiscover = new AutoDiscover();
        $autoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(
                array('use' => 'literal',
                        'namespace' => 'http://localhost/webservice/soap')
        );


        $autoDiscover->setBindingStyle(
                array('style' => 'rpc',
                        'transport' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http')
        );

        $autoDiscover->setComplexTypeStrategy(new ArrayOfTypeComplex());

        // $service is the class that does the handling of functions 
        $autoDiscover->setClass($service);
        $autoDiscover->setUri($wsdl);

       $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

        $response->setContent($autoDiscover->toXml());

        } else {

            $server = new Server('http://localhost/webservice/soap?wsdl' 
            );
              // $service is the class that does the handling of functions 
            $server->setObject($service);
            $response->setContent($server->handle());

            }

            return $response;
           }
```

Service class

```
 class service
  {
 /**
 * 
 * @param string $Email
 * @return int $Credit
 */

public function checkCredits($Email)

{
    $validator = new email();

    if (!$validator->isValid($Email))
    {

        return new \SoapFault('5', 'Please Provide an Email');


    }
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('EMAIL'=>$Email))

    $row = $rowset->current();
    $credits = $row->CREDITS;
    return $credits;
}

  }
```

Request is :

```
 try{
 $sClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost/webservice/soap?wsdl');
  $params = "email";
  $response = $sClient->checkCredits($params);
 var_dump($response);
 } catch(SoapFault $e){

var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: where is the request?

Comment: $client = new SoapClient("wsdl", array('trace' => 1, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, 'style'=> SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                                     'use'      => SOAP_LITERAL));
 
 $result = $client->webservice('137');
 $rr= $client->getLastResponse();
 print_r($rr);

Comment: so do you have a function that handles this specific call?

Comment: try it like this: $client = new SoapClient('http://url?wsdl'); with your path to the wsdl

Comment: That is how I am doing it. its just i removed the wsdl from code for security reasons.

Comment: DevZer0, yes i have function named Webservice handling it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I handle my functions with SoapClient:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://url/Service.svc?wsdl');
$var = array('arg' => 10,
            'VA' => 48);
$varresponse = $client->Function($var);
print_r( $varresponse->FunctionResult);
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks but its not working still. My webservice is in php as well not .net. Could that might be whats causing it ?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if it's in PHP or .NET
What is your error?

Comment: If you can't use SoapClient to retrieve the SOAP response in a PHP object, then use SimpleXML to parse the soap response.

Comment: Can you please give me an example. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514304/php-converting-xml-to-array-in-php-parsing-a-soap-xml-in-php-and-storing-it

Comment: But isnt that response in xml already. How can i parse and returned object using simplexml ?

Comment: Ok. how did you set up your server?

Comment: $server = new Server('wsdl');

            $server->setObject($service);
            $response->setContent($server->handle());

Comment: check my new answer. you need to set it up in that way, because right now you only have a soap server object.

Comment: Thanks. But inside the Soap object I have a class called service that is handling the functions. Do i need to add functions individually. I have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your soapserver should look a bit like this:

```
<?php
if(!extension_loaded("soap")){
  dl("php_soap.dll");
}

    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
    $server = new SoapServer("hello.wsdl");

    function doHello($yourName){
      return "Hello, ".$yourName;
    }

    $server->AddFunction("doHello");
    $server->handle();

?>
```

How did you set up yours? Do you return anything?

Now, your client should look like this:

```
<?php

try{
  $sClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost/test/wsdl/hello.xml');
  $params = "Name";
  $response = $sClient->doHello($params);
  var_dump($response);
} catch(SoapFault $e){

  var_dump($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But inside the Soap object I have a class called service that is handling the functions. Do i need to add functions individually. I have updated my question please have a look