# Get values from XML using php 5.3

Tags: php, xml, xml-namespaces, simplexml

How can i get errorCode and errorMsg values? I went trough many example but still struggling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:doOperationsResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:bulkdeployer.easy.gintel.com" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <result href="#id0"/>
  </ns1:doOperationsResponse>
  <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:bulkdeployer.easy.gintel.com" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:ResponseType">
   <errorCode xsi:type="xsd:int">0</errorCode>
   <errorMsg xsi:type="xsd:string">No errors</errorMsg>
  </multiRef>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I have tried:

```
  $xml= simplexml_load_string($content);
  $xml->registerXPathNamespace('nam','urn:bulkdeployer.easy.gintel.com'); // need to register namespace

  $return_code = $xml->xpath('//nam:errorCode');
  $return_msg = $xml->xpath('//nam:errorMsg');
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514304/php-converting-xml-to-array-in-php-parsing-a-soap-xml-in-php-and-storing-it

Comment: it works without prefix: `$return_code = $xml->xpath('//errorCode');
  $return_msg = $xml->xpath('//errorMsg');`

Comment: @splash58 you are right!  I have accepted your answer.

Comment: I can't write an answer because i know nothing abour namespace and can't explain why it works so. I just know that :)